# Laravel get which Categories belong to logged user in ManyToMany

Tags: php, laravel

in my simple blog web application i have some `categories` and `users` which stored in database, each `category` may belongs to one or many user and i try to get them to show each user logged, for implementing this scenario i have this tables:

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->string('name')->nullable();
    $table->string('family')->nullable();
    $table->string('username')->unique();

    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
});

Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->index()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('category_name');
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
});
```

and then, creating `many to many` table:

```php
Schema::create('category_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->index();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->primary(['user_id','category_id']);
});
```

now how can i get categories of logged user like with this code:

```php
$categories = Category::whereNull('category_id')
    ->with(['childrenCategories', 'users' => function ($query) {
        //$query->where('id',auth()->user()->id);
    }])
    ->withCount('posts')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [query the relationship existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) with `whereHas` to get only the categories which belongs to the authenticated user.

```
$categories = Category::whereNull('category_id')
    ->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', auth()->user()->id);
    })
    ->with([
        'childrenCategories', 
        'users' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('id', auth()->user()->id);
        }
    ])
    ->withCount('posts')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

inside Your User Model, add the relationship btw both Models:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category');
}
```

inside Your Controller:

```
 $user = App\Models\User::find(1);
```

now you can get the categories of your user

```
foreach ($user->categories as $category) {
//
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many